# Is there any connection between distributive lattices and planar graphs?

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, lattice-orders, planar-graphs

I'm asking this because there are very similar theroems describing these properties: A lattice is distributive if and only if it does not contain N5 (pentagon) or M3 (diamond) and according to Kuratowski's theorem, a graph is planar if and only if it does not contain a subgraph which is homeomorphic to K5 or K3,3. Can these forbidden sublattices/subgraphs be somehow paired? Is there any reason why these theorems look so similar?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Two graph $G,G'$ are isomorphic if there is an isomorphism from the subdivision of one graph into a subdivision of another.    A lattice is a partially ordered set in which every two elements has a unique supremum and a unique infimum. A lattice is distributive if the operation of join and meet distribute over each other. a lattice graph is a graph that can be embedded into some Euclidean space to form a regular tilling.  A regular tilling is a tilling in which the symmetric group of the tilling act transitively on the flags of tilling. A flag is a tuple of incident vertex,edge,face.

Comment: I don’t know if they are related, but perhaps such characterizations are more common than you think. I think you would be interested in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_graph_characterization

Comment: Thank you, this was interesting. So it may be only due to some coincidence, but if anyone had yet an idea why even the numbers are so similar, I'd be still excited to learn!

Comment: I believe this similarity is purely coincidental.

Comment: The question was already [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3633084/is-there-any-connection-between-distributive-lattices-and-planar-graphs).